# Object size with no scale in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Currently I'm creating unity game in which I need to generate terrain dynamically. I have an idea for doing this, bud i don't know hot to check size(exactly width) of my terrain, to instantiate it next to another terrain. I searched a bit for a solution but everything I found didn't work for me. The model of terrain is created in blender and not scaled. Please note that i'm beginner.

```
public Renderer rend; 
public GameObject terr; 
public void SpawnChild(GameObject prefab, Vector3 relativePosition, Quaternion relativeRotation) 
{ 
GameObject childObj = Instantiate(prefab);
childObj.transform.parent = transform; 
childObj.transform.localPosition = relativePosition; 
childObj.transform.localRotation = relativeRotation;
childObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.one; 
} 

void Start () 
{ 
Vector3 center = rend.bounds.center; 
SpawnChild(terr, center, Quaternion.identity); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this:
`public Renderer rend;

    public GameObject terr;


    public void SpawnChild(GameObject prefab, Vector3 relativePosition, Quaternion relativeRotation)

    {


        GameObject childObj = Instantiate(prefab);

        childObj.transform.parent = transform;

        childObj.transform.localPosition = relativePosition;

        childObj.transform.localRotation = relativeRotation;

        childObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

    }



    void Start () {

        Vector3 center = rend.bounds.center;

        SpawnChild(terr, center, Quaternion.identity);

    }`

Comment: It spawned the object too far away

Comment: Never put code in comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36087142/edit) and put the code there.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you want to Instantiate terrain next to one another
You can do this like this:

```
Instantiate(prefab, transform.position + transform.scale, transform.rotation);
```

This should create the childObj at the top-right corner of the parent so what you can do is `childObj.transform.position.axis = transform.position.axis` and axis of course being the axis you want it to be the same as the parent so maybe `x` axis.